# executable not found; please configure clang-executable

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

Clang format is not working in VSCode Linux (Ubuntu).
After installing `clang-format` in VSCode, I tried to invoke it and it is giving this error:

```
executable not found; please configure clang-executable. 
Clang-format is available under '/home/alex/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.10.3/LLVM/bin/clang-format'
```

Answer (score 9):

My system & settings:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Visual Studio 1.51.1
- VS extension: Clang-formatter v1.9.0 by Xaver

After installing the extension it was not working. When I looked inside the extension folder in the home folder

```
~/.vscode/extensions/xaver*

xaver.clang-format-1.9.0/
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── clang-format.png
├── LICENSE.txt
├── node_modules
│   └── sax
│       ├── lib
│       │   └── sax.js
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── package.json
│       └── README.md
├── out
│   └── src
│       ├── clangMode.js
│       ├── clangPath.js
│       └── extension.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── tslint.json
└── typings.json
```

Since no bin files were there I installed clang separately with:

```
sudo apt install clang-format
```

After this installation the extension in Visual Studio started working.

Comment: A side note, on Ubuntu 18.04 `sudo apt-get install clang-formatter` complains about "E: Unable to locate package clang-formatter."

Comment: @LouisGo try `sudo apt-get install clang-format`

Answer (score 3):

Even thought I tried configuring the vscode setting.json it was not picking up. Then got the info from https://web.archive.org/web/20170517131553/http://www.codepool.biz/vscode-format-c-code-windows-linux.html and created a link to the target

```
sudo ln -s /home/alex/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.10.3/LLV
M/bin/clang-format /usr/bin/clang-format
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format
```

Then it should be working!

Then try the Clang-format with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>